# #each block in Meteor template duplicates element after element is moved

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a template that iterates over a collection as such:

```
<template name="task_list">
    <form id="tasks">
        {{#each tasks}}     
            {{> task}}
        {{/each}}
    </form>
</template>

<template name="task">
    <label class="checkbox" id="label-{{_id}}">
        <input type="checkbox" id="{{_id}}" {{{completed}}} /> {{text}}
    </label>
</template>
```

I made this a jQuery sortable, which allows the user to drag and drop within this list. When the user is done moving an item and the DOM is done rendering, I update the collection that this template uses.

This works fine when the user drags an item down, however when an item is dragged up, Meteor duplicates the item that was just dragged.

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you've told both Meteor and jQuery to manage the same DOM elements. They both try to update the elements, and they end up fighting :) It's like driving a car.. only one person can drive at once.

You've got two options:

- Have Meteor manage the elements. In that case, you need to find a way to tell the other library (jQuery in this case) to not actually physically move the elements in the DOM.. just have it give you a callback and let you know what the user wants to do. Then you update the collection, and Meteor updates the screen.
- Have jQuery manage the elements. Put this entire section of your page inside `{{#constant}}..{{/constant}}` and Meteor will leave it alone. It's up to you to call `<collectionname>.find(<query>).observe({...})` and use jQuery to create/move/remove the list items in response to the callbacks that `observe` gives you. (You can still make each individual item reactive, using `Meteor.render`, and you can even generate the items out of a template if you want, using something like `Meteor.render(Template.<mytemplate>)`).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a wild guess, without seeing the JS:

Meteor is seeing that the list of elements doesn't match its list of objects that it's using for the `each` statement, so it adds what it considers to be the missing ones.

I would try getting a callback when the drag ends, and then in that callback make sure that Meteor knows which order the elements are supposed to be displayed in, so that when it re-renders the `each` block, it doesn't get confused about the correct order of elements and overwrite it.

Hope that's on the right track!  It can be tricky to get callback-oriented code to function well in conjunction with Meteor's reactivity.